# vector function "push_back" keeps rewriting the value to the same slot in memory

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

The push_back method of the std::vector isn't putting the second console input in the v[1] slot, it keeps overwriting it in the  v[0]

I tried to search for other answers to this but the code and answer is too complicated for me to follow, im trying to keep it simple (But i tried using pointers, just got a bunch of errors)

**My Method:**

```
      vector<string> createtable(std::vector<std::string> v, std::string insertedstr) {
        std::vector<std::string> vcreate;
        vcreate.push_back(insertedstr + " ");

            return vcreate;
}
```

**Main:**

```
                   int main()
                {
                    int option;
                    std::string insertedstr;
                    std::vector<std::string> v;
                cin >> insertedstr;
                   v = createtable(v, insertedstr);

                for (int i = 0; i <=v.size(); i++) {
                    cout << v[i] << endl;
        }
        cin >> insertedstr;
   v = createtable(v, insertedstr);
            for (int i = 0; i <= v.size(); i++) {


    cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
        return 0;

        }
```

Edit:    I want to eventually write a menu for this so I want to have an infinite amount of push_backs, so just calling v.push_back in the main won't work for me

Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you want to put everything in the same vector or not?!

Comment: Yes all in the same vector but my second cin keeps overwriting it to v[0]

Comment: If you do want them all in the same vector, why do you say "just calling v.push_back in the main won't work for me"?

Comment: Because I want to have an infinite amount of them to call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `vector` in each call to `createTable`, not reusing an existing `vector`; you're not constantly inserting into `v[0]`, you're constantly replacing `v` with a whole new vector that only has a single element. The second call to `createTable` should probably just be a direct call to `v.push_back(insertedString);`.

Alternatively, remove the `vcreate` declaration and actually use the `v` passed into the function instead (which is still wasteful, because it's constantly copying and replacing `vector`s instead of pushing onto an existing one directly, but it would at least be logically correct).

Comment: Well I want to eventually write a menu for this that can add infinitely number of elements to the vector

Comment: Then remove the declaration/use of `vcreate`, stop returning anything from `createTable`, and have `createTable` accept the first argument by reference `void createtable(std::vector<std::string>& v, std::string insertedstr) { insertedstr += " "; v.push_back(insertedstr); }`. Will save an awful lot of expensive copies recreating your "infinite" element `vector`.

Comment: Well but then it won't store anything at all into the vector v

Comment: You'd stop reassigning `v` outside the function, because the function call would be passing `v` in by reference (the `&` I added to the prototype), updating it in place without explicitly returning a new `vector`. When you accept by value and return by value, you're _constantly_ copy-constructing, doing a single `push_back` then returning and replacing the old `v`, causing a destruction of the old contents of `v` (and pre-C++11, causing yet another copy construction and destruction of the version inside the function as part of the return).

Comment: Oh my gosh, something as simple as one & made me get stuck for 1.5 hours. It makes sense though. Thank you!!!!

Comment: What I was doing was putting the dereference operator there, my mistake, because it still takes it to the value

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually writing the second input into anything. Push_back is only called once (inside the function called at `v = createtable(v, insertedstr);`), so it will only contain the one value. You need to actually call push_back with the second value that is supposed to get into the vector.

Comment: Sorry about that, I kept toying with it for some time and forgot to put that back on there

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> createtable(std::vector<std::string> v, std::string insertedstr) {
    //std::vector<std::string> vcreate; // Not required
    v.push_back(insertedstr + " ");

    return v;
}
```

Problem was with this function. You were creating new vector `vcreate` every time instead of using passed vector `v`. So you will have new vector of size 1 every time.

Comment: How does triggering out of bounds access solve anything? That loop is perfectly fine, in that it doesn't access invalid indices, accessing `v[1]` when `v.size() == 1` guarantees invalid access.

Comment: @ShadowRanger i didn't mention but he should have a valid vector of size at least 2.

Comment: Well, yeah. He doesn't have that, though, that's his whole problem, so saying "Once you solve the problem, you could hardcode an index that (if the problem is solved) doesn't even need hardcoding (because the `size` will go up and the loop will cover it seamlessly)" is not answering any question that has been asked.